Radius of convergence of real analytic functions
Let $f: \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ be a function that is analytic at every point in $\mathbb{R}$ except at a single point $x_0$.
Radius of Convergence Near $x_0$:
Can we prove that the radius of convergence of the Taylor series of $f$ around any point $x \in \mathbb{R}$ is equal to $|x - x_0|$? In other words, is the radius of convergence of the Taylor series centered at $x$ precisely the distance from $x$ to the point $x_0$ where $f$ is not analytic?
Radius of Convergence on $\mathbb{R}$:
In particular, if $f: \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ is analytic at every point in $\mathbb{R}$, does it follow that the Taylor series of $f$ around any point $x_0 \in \mathbb{R}$ converges not only in a neighborhood of $x_0$ but on the entire real line $\mathbb{R}$? More precisely, does this imply that the radius of convergence of the Taylor series centered at $x_0$ is infinite?

Of cause not: the radius of convegence at any real point is the distance to the next singular point in $\mathbb C$, that may be nearer than $x_0$

See $1/(x^2+1)$ for a simple example of a real analytic function which is not entire

Replace $\mathbb{R}$ with $\mathbb{C}$ and I think the answer to every one of your questions is yes

@ conorad Thanks for your comment. Could you please elaborate how your counter example proves the answer to both the questions is negative. Thanks in advance

@QC_QAOA Thanks. Could you please elaborate a bit more on what makes the difference in analyticity in $\mathbb{R}$ and in $\mathbb{C}$

Posting an answer since it will become too involved for a comment. I will answer your second questions first and then use that answer to answer your first question.
Question 2
To your first point: the function $\frac{1}{x^2+1}$ is analytic everywhere. This can be easily shown since
$$\frac{d^k}{dx^k} \frac{1}{x^2+1}=\frac{P(x)}{(x^2+1)^{k+1}}$$
for some polynomial $P(x)$. This polynomial will have two important properties: the largest coefficient will be less than or equal to $3^{k} k!$ in absolute value and the degree of $P(x)$ will be $k$. We can show this by induction, assume it is true for some $k\in\mathbb{N}$ (the base case is easy to check). Then
$$\frac{d^{k+1}}{dx^{k+1}} \frac{1}{x^2+1}=\frac{d}{dx}\frac{d^k}{dx^k} \frac{1}{x^2+1}=\frac{d}{dx}\frac{P(x)}{(x^2+1)^{k+1}}$$
$$=\frac{P'(x)(x^2+1)^{k+1}-P(x)(k+1)(2x)(x^2+1)^{k}}{(x^2+1)^{2k+2}}=\frac{P'(x)(x^2+1)-P(x)(k+1)(2x)}{(x^2+1)^{k+2}}$$
This formula also helps us prove the two facts about $Q(x)=P'(x)(x^2+1)-P(x)(k+1)(2x)$. First, let $q$ be the largest coefficient of $P(x)$. Then the largest coefficient of $P'(x)(x^2+1)$ can at most be $kq$ (using our assumption on the degree of $P(x)$) and the largest coefficient of $P(x)(k+1)(2x)$ can at most be $2(k+1)q$. Put together, the largest coefficient of $Q(x)$ is less than or equal to $kq+2(k+1)q< 3(k+1)q$. A further induction proof proves the statement.
The degree of $Q(x)$ is also easy to see: the degree of $P'(x)(x^2+1)$ is $k+1$ and the degree of $P(x)(k+1)(2x)$ is $k+1$. So the degree of $Q(x)$ is less than or equal to $k+1$. Using these facts about the derivatives of $f(x)$ gives us a bound on its magnitude
$$\left|\frac{d^k}{dx^k}\left. \frac{1}{x^2+1}\right|_a\right|\leq  (3(|a|+1))^k k!$$
Note here I have used the fact that $|a|^k\leq (|a|+1)^k$ for all $a\in\mathbb{R}$. Thus, the series expansion of $f(x)=\frac{1}{x^2+1}$ at any $a$ is given by
$$f(x)=\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{f^{(n)}(a)(x-a)^n}{n!}$$
Further this has a non-zero radius of convergence since
$$\leq \sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{|f^{(n)}(a)||x-a|^n}{n!}\leq  \sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{(3(|a|+1))^n n!|x-a|^n}{n!}=\sum_{n=0}^\infty (3(|a|+1)|x-a|)^n$$
This converges if $3(|a|+1)|x-a|<1$ which will happen if $|x-a|<\frac{1}{3|a|+3}$, that is the radius of convergence greater than or equal to $\frac{1}{3|a|+3}$.
However, we know that at $a=0$
$$\frac{1}{x^2+1}=\sum_{n=0}^\infty (-1)^n x^{2n}\text{ for all }x\in (-1,1)$$
but diverges for $x=1$. Thus, $\frac{1}{x^2+1}$ is an example of an analytic everywhere function on the reals that nevertheless has a finite radius of convergence everywhere.
Question 1
Now, consider the function
$$f(x)=\frac{1}{x^2+1}+\frac{1}{x-10}$$
Clearly, this function has a single singularity in the reals at $x_0=10$. We proved the first portion of it analytic earlier and I believe you can easily prove that $\frac{1}{x-10}$ is analytic everywhere except $x_0=10$. However, since this is the composition of two analytic functions, we can write its series at $0$ as
$$f(x)=\sum_{n=0}^\infty \left[[ (-1)^nx^{2n} -\frac{x^n}{10^{n+1}}\right]$$
Again, this function has a radius of convergence of $1$ which is less than the distance from $0$ to $10$ (ie $10$).
General Discussion
One major difference between $\mathbb{R}$ and $\mathbb{C}$ is that differentiable in the reals does not imply that the function is analytic. Even more so, infinitely differentiable does not imply the function is analytic. However, in the complex numbers if a function is differentiable once, then it is differentiable infinitly many times and furthermore it is analytic on some set.

@QC_QAQA Thank you so much for the details
